# How to create item in folder in sharepoint list using Graph api?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

Need to create item in folder in sharepoint list (not library) by Graph api. Can't find working solution for this.This is possible or the situation is like with hyperlink fields and graph api. Basic thing, but not supported

It doesn't look like it's possible to do this with graph api
Looks like `/sites/{site-id}/drive` endpoint works only with libraries

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site id}/lists/{list id}/items/{folder id}` doesn't work either

Help please :(

Answer (score 0):

It appears you would use this POST request:

```
POST /sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-create?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http